# Increase SQL Bulk Copy speed on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, sqlbulkcopy

I am working on a project where I have to move an on-premises application over to Azure. We have an upload utility that transfers about 150,000 records to the web app (MVC App). Unfortunately, I was getting timeout issues after I migrated to Azure. I made several changes including using `SqlBulkCopy` and Store Procedures instead of using `SqlCommand`. Now, the timeout issue has been resolve but the data upload is taking about 5mins to upload the 150,000 records into a table on Azure.

I am using a trial version on Azure, and my Database DTU is 20. Now, I would love to keep it at 20 because of the cost. I have a small budget That I am working with. Note, Database Size isnt a problem. I am well below the quota.

Any Suggestions on how I can decrease the time to insert those 150,000 records?

Code Sample

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                    {
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Barcode", "Barcode");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SubCategory", "SubCategory");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ItemDescription", "ItemDescription");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CreateDate", "CreateDate");
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("RevisedDate", "RevisedDate");

                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Items";
                        try
                        {
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtTblData);
                            destinationConnection.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            this.Logs.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

FYI: During the insert operation the DTU for my database reaches 100%.

Comment: Do you have to upload all 150K at once? You might try sending batches of 10K rows each, either as separate data tables or via the BatchSize property. If possible, reduce the number of indexes on the target table and load in order by the clustered index.

Comment: I have a batchSize set to 10K. From what I am seeing in the database, there is an Index on the PK only.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: Is source data ordered by the PK?

Comment: No, the source data is coming from a json file, then inserted into a datatable and then copied using sqlbulkcopy. Apologies if I left out any details.

Comment: One thing you might try is make sure the DataTable columns are strongly typed to match the target table and especially max length for string columns. The default string length is -1 (2GB) which is an issue for TVPs but I'm not sure about SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: The fact you're on a trial doesn't really mean anything; Azure is the same, regardless of billing model. That said: DTU is not a capacity measurement, and without increasing DTU (and the fact your DTU usage is hitting 100%) I'm not sure how you're going to appreciably increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the option `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock` will increase the performance.

So if you can lock the table, you should without a doubt use it.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
{
    // ...code...
}
```

Outside of this configuration, there is not a lot of stuff you can do since you already use SqlBulkCopy. The bottle neck is your database performance that you cannot upgrade because of the budget.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Table locking Jonathan mentioned, the only real way to increase performance is to increase the DTUs for the service.

However you don't need to leave the database on the higher setting forever, if this bulk load is a infrequent operation you could temporary raise the DTUs of the database, do your load, then lower the DTUs back down. You would only be billed at the higher rate for the time you where actually uploading.

You can change the database via code using the the [Azure SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql) and functions in the [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.DatabasesOperationsExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.databasesoperationsextensions.begincreateorupdate?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_DatabasesOperationsExtensions_BeginCreateOrUpdate_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_IDatabasesOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_Models_Database_) class and setting the [`RequestedServiceObjectiveId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.database.requestedserviceobjectiveid?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_Models_Database_RequestedServiceObjectiveId) value with [a higher tier objective](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.serviceobjectiveid?view=azure-dotnet) (The 20 DTUs you are on now is a S1 objective, you could move up to a S2 (50 DTUs) during the bulk load) on the `Database` object you pass in to the update function.

Comment: Noted. Would the Elastic Pool do the same thing or your solution offers more control? THanks again.

Comment: Eleastic pool is only useful if you have multiple databases, you still pay for the single DTU price but the DTUs can be shared between many databases so so long as they don't all have a peak at the same time they all can scale up and down as needed.